# prevent DEL command from deleting a specific file

Tags: windows, cmd, del

I'm a first semester student, searched everywhere with no luck, 
I have 2 questions in an assignment that are basically the same - or at least that's what I think.

First: You want to protect yourself from deleting with your DEL command your program named PROG.EXE. Specify some ways to do this.

Second: Write a command through which a file `Pass.log` could be protected by deleting with a command `del Pass.log`

Is there a way to protect them from DEL command within cmd?

Comment: In UNIX/Linux, you can make an alias of every command, like `alias del='echo do not delete a file'` (not tested). This replaces the general `del` command by the mentioned error message, but I don't know if this is possible in Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**On windows:**

- You can set the file as read only . (Right click on file -> properties  -> General Tab -> check the "read only" checkbox)
  Or using command: `Attrib +R 1.txt`
- Using Security tab you can add a "Deny" on the modify privilege from the file. (Right click on file -> properties  -> Security tab -> Edit for each line check the Deny near Modify)

**On Unix/Linux:**
You can remove the write privilege from every one using `chmod` command. like `chmod -w PROG.EXE`

## For the second task: (on windows)

- `Attrib +R 1.txt` command will set the file as read only.
- `icacls 1.txt /deny <User>:M` command will set the security deny for User for Modification and deletion. you shoud put your user instead of `<User>`
- `icacls 1.txt /deny <User>:D` command will prevent you only the deletion of the file not the modification of it (even to an empty file)

Comment: Yes, this way it will not be deletable anymore I know, for first question this solution is perfect. 
But for the second question he is asking for a command that does the same job, that the part Im lost in :3

Comment: Don't use simple or generic rights such as "M", "D", and "GW" in a deny access-control entry (ACE). Simple and generic rights are actually a set of rights that include required rights such as `SYNCHRONIZE` and `FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES`. Denying the set makes all normal file access impossible for the user. A deny ACE should only deny specific rights such as "DE" (delete) or "DC" (delete child), e.g. `icacls "." /deny <user>:(DC)` and `icacls "1.txt" /deny <user>:(DE)`.

Comment: Note the user can still delete the file if we don't deny delete-child access on the containing directory ("."). Similarly in Unix being able to delete a file is controlled by write access to the containing *directory*. Denying write access to the file won't prevent deleting it. Also, many Unix systems have a notion of file attributes and flags that includes immutabilty, but it may require superuser access. For example in Linux we can mark a file as immutable, e.g. via `sudo chattr +i "1.txt"` and read the attributes via `lsattr "1.txt"`.